# I cannot run my simulation program using omnet++ in Windows 7

Tags: omnet++

I am learning omnet++ to simulate a network. The code in packeage.ned is shown as follows:

```
    package helloworld.simulations;

    import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.FlatNetworkConfigurator;
    import inet.node.inet.Router;
    import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;

    @license(LGPL);
    network Network
    {
        @display("bgb=519,314");
        submodules:
            Client: StandardHost {
                @display("p=82,217");
            }
            router: Router {
                @display("p=218,117");
            }
            Server: StandardHost {
                @display("p=361,198");
            }
            flatNetworkConfigurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator {
                @display("p=296,46;b=45,44");
            }
        connections:
            Client.ethg++ <--> router.ethg++;
            router.ethg++ <--> Server.ethg++;
    }
```

And the code in omnetpp.ini is shown as follows:

```
    [General]
    network = helloworld.simulations.Network

    **.Client.numTcpApps = 1
    **.Client.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPBasicClientApp"
    **.Client.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "Server"
    **.Client.tcpApp[0].connectPort = 80
    **.Client.tcpApp[0].thinkTime = 0s
    **.Client.tcpApp[0].idleInterval = 0s

    **.Server.numTcpApps = 1
    **.Server.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPEchoApp"
    **.Server.tcpApp[0].localPort = 80

    **.ppp[*].queueType = "DropTailQueue"
    **.ppp[*].queue.frameCapacity = 10
```

However, when I run this program, I encounter the following problem:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky4ja.png)

Now, I do not how to solve this problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you built `INET`? If yes, go to the `mingw` console and type:

```
opp_run -h nedfunctions -l /d/omnetpp-5.1.1/Projects/inet/src/inet | grep firstAvailableOrEmpty
```

After -l there is a path to your `libINET.dll file`. You should see something like:

> firstAvailableOrEmpty : string firstAvailableOrEmpty(...)
>       Accepts any number of strings, interprets them as NED type names (qualified or unqualified), and returns the first one that exists and
>   its C++ implementation class is also available. Returns empty string
>   if none of the types are available.

Moreover, the instance of `FlatNetworkConfigurator` **must** be called `configurator`, not `flatNetworkConfigurator`.

**EDIT**
Go to `INET` properties then select `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options...` | `Compile` tab | `More >>` and ensure that you have set `Export include path for other projects` and `Force compiling object files for use in DLLs`. And in `Target` tab set `Export this shared/static library for other projects`. Then rebuild `INET`.

Then in your project:

1. In `Properties` | `Project References` make sure that `inet` is selected.
2. In `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select directory with source files | `Options...` | `Compile` and make sure that the following options are checked:

   - `Add include paths exported from referenced projects`
   - `Add include dir and other compile options from enabled project features`
3. In `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select directory with source files | `Options...` | `Link`  and make sure that the following options are checked:

   - `Link with libraries exported from referenced projects`
   - `Add libraries and other linker options from enabled project features`
4. Rebuild your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry, I am a beginner. I still have a problem. I have type the string in mingw console and obtain the following result:    firstAvailableOrEmpty : string firstAvailableOrEmpty(...)

So, how to do next? Thank you again!

Comment: How did you create your example - as a new project or a folder inside INET?

Comment: I create my example as a new project. Not a folder inside INET.

Comment: Which version of INET do you use? I have extended my answer, I hope that it will help you.

Comment: I tried again. But it still does not work. The version of INET is 3.6.1. And the version of OMNET++ is 5.1.1. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Try to check whether both `inet` and your project have the same Build Configuration - by right click on project, `Build Configuration` | `Set Active`. If both have gcc-debug and there is still an error, change both to gcc-release, clean and rebuild projects.